# Adding Custom Logos to Shipping Methods in Magento

Tags: magento2

¿How can I add custom logos to the shipping methods in Magento? I need specific logos to appear for each shipping method during the checkout process. What is the best way to achieve this, and where should I make the code modifications in Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be mostly CSS and knockout html work.
Use a CSS selector with the custom attribute match.

The original implementation of the template is in knockout template

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html
```

1. Override the html with your theme, add `attr` attribute. `attr` is the knockout attribute to update node attributes.

```html
<tr class="row"
    click="element.selectShippingMethod"
    attr="'data-carrier-code': method.carrier_code">
```

2. Use `tr.row[data-carrier-code="my_super_carrier"]` or similar within CSS.
3. Use CSS background, padding, margin to put things together.

Good luck